# How to get array values to laravel controller and insert into the database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I can get array  values on scrpit array .

[image]

Script is

```
 $(document).on('click', '#bulk_delete', function()
    {
        var id = [];

        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to  Delete this data?"))
        {
            $('.student_checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                id.push($(this).val());
            });
            if(id.length > 0)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"del",
                    method:"get",
                    data:{id:id},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                        $('#dTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Please select atleast one checkbox");
            }
        }
    });
```

How to get these array values to laravel controller and insert into the database

Route is

```
Route::get('/del', 'AjaxdataController@ins');
```

and AjaxdataController.php is

```
 public function ins(Request $request )
    {

    }
```

Comment: Did you call the controller? Here as per the above code you are calling the route.Right? Provide code of route as well as controller so it will be helpful.

Comment: Edited @SohilChamadia

Comment: Please check the answer that i had written.That may help you.

Comment: You need to pass this as a post request and change your route as well. Right now you are doing a get request so ideally the `id` will be passed in the URL to which your route is not capturing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change method type of your ajax from get to post like this.

```
method="POST"
```

and change your route to post like this

```
Route::post('/del', 'AjaxdataController@ins');
```

and call id in your controller like this

```
public function ins(Request $request )
{
    $id = $request->id;
}
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the below code in the controller.You will retrieve the id over there that is passed from ajax.

```
public function ins(Request $request )
    {
       print_r($request->id);
    }
```

You will get the id and then you can use the method of laravel to insert that data into the database.

Use this code in routes file instead of your code :

```
Route::post('/del/{id}', 'AjaxdataController@ins');
```

Comment: Change the method from get to post in your ajax script code as well as in your route file also.

Comment: all changed but no result.

Comment: What's the use of `{id}` in the route? OP obviously wants to insert multiple ids

Comment: As per the code of ajax script @TestCheck is trying to pass array of id so it can be pass as a parameter.

Comment: Parameters will be passed in the request. `'/del/{id}'` _requires_ one parameter 'id' to be present in the URL, calling just `/del` will probably result in the URL not being found